# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException, while NOT actually running in MainThread

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets

There are many previous questions regarding the `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` exception ,  which is essentially a protective approach by android to prevent us from freezing UI.

Opening a socket from another thread (hence, not the `MainThread`) should solve this issue:

```
Thread t = new Thread (new Runnable() { 
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
            Socket socket = new Socket ( SOME_IP_AS_STRING , SOME_PORT_AS_INT);
                    // do some IO with socket
            }
            catch (Exception e) {} 
            } 
            });

        t.run();
```

However, this code throws the mentioned exception  - `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`, 
and when debugging (using the Android Studio), it looks like `run()` is running under the `MainThread` after all, which makes no sense.

where do I got it wrong?

Comment: You are, you know. The exception isn't wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `.run()` which actually **will** run the `Thread` in your main `UI` Thread. You need to call `.start()` instead to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. Try to run your code in [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) , For more detail refer [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)